# change backgroundimage tint of a button on select

Tags: ios, uibutton, background-image, tint

Is this possible in objective C? I have a layout that uses random colors and I'd like the selected buttons to match so I'd like to tint them on click but not sure if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so but you can change the color of the image and set it as the image for state highlighted.